# how add one line with xml tag to one file with sed command

Tags: xml, shell, sed

I have one String XML string to add to one file before line2 .

```
<script><![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam('Enable500', 1);]]></script>
```

I try the command

```
 sed "2 <script><![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam(\'Enable500\', 1);]]></script>" -i mytest.log
```

get error :

```
-bash: ![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam: event not found
```

I know I should escape  the special characters, but I do not know how to escape these special characters in the Sed command.

Comment: I respect that you are asking for an sed solution. However let me make the obligatory comment that processing XML with non-XML text processing tools is prone to errors if even the smallest of the assumptions on the input fail.

Comment: Please explain your thinking of the sed command you have shown. I see the address of line two, then I only see the text you want to insert. Shouldn't there be an sed command somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

`!` needs to be escaped too. In the `sed` command scope, `!` reverses restrictions and is usually paired with `p` or `d`. So, the following command should add the line

```
<script><![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam('Enable500', 1);]]></script>
```

before the second line in your file:

```
sed -e "2i<script><\![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam(\'Enable500\', 1);]]></script>" -i mytest.log
```

Comment: Please augment your code-only answer with some explanation. That would make it more useful and help fighting the misconception that StackOverflow is a free code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` in a double quoted string is a special char that is used for [history expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/History-Interaction.html).

Use single quoted string instead:

```
sed -i '2i<script><![CDATA[context.ExtendParams.setParam('"'"'Enable500'"'"', 1);]]></script>' file
```

Note: `2i` means that we need to insert at Line #2.